# Stepped Area Chart translation

Tags: traducción, informática

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/steppedareachart

So, Gráfico de área escalonada no suena muy bien...

What would you suggest for a translation?

Comment: Yo lo veo como una buena traducción, es un gráfico de área y está escalonado.

Comment: En mi opinión, debería ser *gráfica de áreas escalonadas*, con *áreas* en plural, ya que hay varias áreas. Ten en cuenta que, en inglés, la palabra *area* es invariable en esta frase porque funciona como adjetivo.

Answer (score 3):

Google translates "Area Chart" as "Gráfico de Áreas".

Just check [Soporte de Google > Gráficos de áreas](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190721?hl=es) (spanish version) and [Google Support > Area chart](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190721?hl=en) (english version).

For this reason I think the best option for "Stepped Area Chart" is "Gráfico de Áreas Escalonadas".

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con esta respuesta. Por las búsquedas que he hecho por Internet, **escalonadas** parece ser el término aceptado para este tipo de gráfica. Por ejemplo: http://jld-excel-grafico.blogspot.com/2006/11/grficos-escalonados-step-charts-con.html

Answer (score 1):

"Gráfico/a de áreas escalonadas" parece una buena traducción, pero es un término que no había aparecido nunca en Internet.

Lo que muestra el enlace de Sebas es ciertamente un gráfico de áreas (y no de líneas, puntos o barras), pero más concretamente es un gráfico escalonado (stepped chart) de áreas apiladas (stacked area).
En otros gráficos escalonados de áreas estas no son apiladas (las áreas se solapan). Si con "stepped area chart" nos estamos refiriéndonos tanto a gráficas apiladas (stacked) como a las no apiladas, entonces "gráfico/a escalonado/a de áreas" o "gráfico/a de áreas escalonadas" serían buenas traducciones, pero de lo contrario creo que habría que "gráfica/o escalonada/o de áreas apiladas" sería un nombre menos ambiguo. Aunque tampoco estos términos entrecomillados aparecen en Google.

Comment: Las gráficas **apiladas** son distintas al gráfico de muestra de la pregunta. **Apiladas** son unas columnas donde hay varios valores en la misma columna, mientras que las **escalonadas** tienen la forma de escalón. Ejemplo de **Apiladas**: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=tipos+de+graficas+de+areas+apiladas

Comment: @Diego: if you hover your pointer over the differen columns of the example chart in the link by Sebas (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/steppedareachart), you'll see, for example, that for 1935 IMDB (red) is 7.9 and Rotten Tomatoes (blue) is 8.4, summing up to 15.5 shown in the chart. So the areas are not overlapped but stacked.

Comment: Me parece muy bien, pero las gráficas con la forma de escalón y con columna tienen nombres distintos. Pueden mostrar la misma información y una se transforma en la otra si juntas o separas la columnas, pero los nombres por los que parece que son conocidas son distintos.

Comment: @Diego, no sé si te entiendo. Hablamos de gráficas de áreas, que no son gráficas de barras (columnas). En ambos casos (tanto barras como áreas), la gráfica puede ser apilada o no. Y la gráfica de áreas puede ser tanto escalonada como no escalonada (la gráfica de barras sólo puede ser escalonada dado que no tiene sentido en ese caso hablar de no escalonadas).